# Why image path is saved as word "images" instead of image name in table column in Codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have to ask this twice here as my question is still unanswered. I don't understand if 'echo' or 'print_r' works differently for images in php & Codeigniter.

I have tried `echo $image;`, `print_r($image);` and `echo $sql = $this->db->last_query();`..

Result for first 2 is 'property_image_1.png' and for 3rd is `UPDATE vbc_property_images SET profile_thumb = 'property_image_1.png' WHERE property_ref_id = '15'`.

Now , my question is that when I run:

Model

```
function update_profile_image($id, $image){
    $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
    $this->db->set('profile_thumb', $image);
    $this->db->update('vbc_property_images');
    //echo $image;
    //print_r($image);
    //echo $sql = $this->db->last_query();
}
// New Added
function get_property_all_images_url($id) {
    $this->db->select('property_images');
    $this->db->from('vbc_property_images');
    $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
$query_result = $query->result_array();
if (empty($query_result)) {
    return FALSE;
}
elseif (count($query_result) > 1) {
    return 0;
}
else{
    $rowId = explode(',',$query_result[0]['property_images']);
    return $rowId;
}
}
```

Controller

```
function property_profile_image_update() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
    $username = $this->session->userdata('v_member_username');
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $image = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data['images_urls'] = $this->my_listings_model->get_property_all_images_url($id); // New Added
    $this->my_listings_model->update_profile_image($id, $image);
    // Some Code
```

Why do I get the word "images" in profile_thumb column of table vbc_property_images?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vbc_property_images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `property_ref_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `v_username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `property_images` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `property_images_thumb` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `profile_thumb` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

URL:

> http://localhost/admin/dashboard/property-profile-image-update/15/property_image_1.png

Comment: Can you brief your question. Cant understand clearly.

Comment: Thanks @Abdulla.. I am not able to update image name in db column. This only inserts a word 'images' instead of image name without any error.

Comment: so in this `print_r($image);` you get an answer??

Comment: Yes ..image name.. example image1.png,, var_dump `string(21) "property_image_11.png"`

Comment: did you try with `'$image'` ??

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner you are getting image name from url, can you please post that url too??

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner there must be something with that query . Can you echo the query echo $sql = $this->db->last_query();; view the result in browser and then view the source code . See if there is any irrelevant things , like js or something else.  IF not then try with this way to update :             $data = array(
               'title' => $title,
               'name' => $name,
               'date' => $date
            );

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the value of $images may be it is an array.

Comment: Thanks @krishnakumar, When I echo or print it gives desired image name.. Can it be still an array? I am new to this.

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner:Try with  var_dump($image) let me know what it returns

Comment: The result is `string(21) "property_image_11.png" `

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner:can u post the table structure.

Comment: Would it be easier if I have another array where the image I am referencing is in it too? I mean if in another array there are 5 images and the image I want is one of those five.. If so I can update the code in question.

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner:could you please post your code in controller

Comment: I have added the code now... A new array in controller and model for that. And Table structure too..

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner you are getting image name from url, can you please post that url too??

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner:I just try with your query its working for me may be issue in some other palce.

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner:yes

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner:I am sorry I don't have that much reputation to chat may be we look for some other options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100763/discussion-between-codeigniter-learner-and-krishnakumar).